# xcoderebuild take so long time Titanium Appcelerator

Tags: ios, xcode, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am using Titanium Appcelerator to make iOS application, when i run app it takes so much time while build xcode project and i searched for it as well.
Main reason is force rebuild command that runs when we run the project i am here to find a solution how can i avoid the force rebuild process in Titanium appcelerator for iOS apps.

this is the command

```
Forcing rebuild: ApplicationDefaults.m has changed since last build
```

Right now its only taking to build app of 9 mins.Thats too much to test a single image size.

I hope question is understandable and will take some attention.
Thanks regards: Ali

Comment: so... on what computer do you run this? Even if it has to do a full rebuild for me it takes max 30 seconds (mid 2012 macbook pro).

Comment: I am using macbook pro late 2011 4GB running and only Appcelerator studio running on it. But many other people has also complained its not only  issue with me. i hope there must be some solution to it.